# Xslt does not work in php but saxon did

Tags: php, xslt, saxon

i am testing my xslt stylesheets sometimes in Kernow with a saxon processor. I always use xslt 1.0 because simplexml or even simpledom can only execute xslt 1.0. the following stylesheet does not work in php:

```
$tagsXml=simpledom_load_file('...xml');
    $dom_sxe=dom_import_simplexml($tagsXml);
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom_sxe = $dom->importNode($dom_sxe, true);
    $dom_sxe = $dom->appendChild($dom_sxe); 
    $proc = new XSLTProcessor();
    $xsl = new DOMDocument;
    $xsl->load('...xslt');
    $proc->importStylesheet($xsl);
    $newXml = $proc->transformToXml($dom);
```

thats the stylesheet were php throw an compilation error that is not possible to compile the when statement `<xsl:when test="count($ctag/ancestor::*[local-name()=current()/local-name() and text()=current()/text()]|$ctag/descendant::*[local-name()=current()/local-name() and text()=current()/text()])&gt;0">`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:output indent="no"/> 
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="tag">

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="related">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[name()!='right' and name()!='rating' and name()!='id' and name()!='geo']">
        <xsl:variable name="ctag" select="."/>

        <xsl:variable name="memxlvl" select="count(//*[max(count(ancestor-or-self::*)) and count(ancestor-or-self::*[.=current()/.]) &gt;0]/ancestor-or-self::*)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="melvl" select="count(current()/ancestor::*)"/>

        <!--<xsl:value-of select="$memxlvl - $melvl"/>-->
        <!--<xsl:value-of select="(($memxlvl - $melvl) >= 0)*($memxlvl - $melvl) - not(($memxlvl - $melvl) >= 0)*($memxlvl - $melvl)"/>-->

        <xsl:for-each select="current()/ancestor::related/descendant::*[text()!=current()/text() and name()!='right' and name()!='rating' and name()!='id' and name()!='geo']">
                <tagconn me="{$ctag/text()}" friend="{./text()}">

                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count($ctag/ancestor::*[local-name()=current()/local-name() and text()=current()/text()]|$ctag/descendant::*[local-name()=current()/local-name() and text()=current()/text()])&gt;0">
                        <xsl:variable name="fmxlvl" select="count(//*[max(count(ancestor-or-self::*)) and count(ancestor-or-self::*[.=current()/.]) &gt;0]/ancestor-or-self::*)"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="flvl" select="count(current()/ancestor::*)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="((($memxlvl - $melvl)-($fmxlvl - $flvl)) >= 0)*(($memxlvl - $melvl)-($fmxlvl - $flvl)) - not((($memxlvl - $melvl)-($fmxlvl - $flvl)) >= 0)*(($memxlvl - $melvl)-($fmxlvl - $flvl))"/>         
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:variable name="fmxlvl" select="count(//*[max(count(ancestor-or-self::*)) and count(ancestor-or-self::*[.=current()/.]) &gt;0]/ancestor-or-self::*)"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="flvl" select="count(current()/ancestor::*)"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="((($memxlvl - $melvl)-($fmxlvl - $flvl)) >= 0)*(($memxlvl - $melvl)-($fmxlvl - $flvl)) - not((($memxlvl - $melvl)-($fmxlvl - $flvl)) >= 0)*(($memxlvl - $melvl)-($fmxlvl - $flvl))+((($memxlvl - $melvl) >= ($fmxlvl - $flvl)))*($memxlvl - $melvl) - not((($memxlvl - $melvl) &lt; ($fmxlvl - $flvl)))*(($fmxlvl - $flvl))"/>            

                </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
             </tagconn>
        </xsl:for-each>     
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="alltags">
<items>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::related"/>
</items>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i know that the template is not perfect and not easy to understand. any experience with such problem in php? thanks for your help!

Robert

Comment: The test looks ok to me, maybe it's a matter of escape characters. How about you replace the `&gt;` with `!=` to see if that's the case?

Comment: well i tried such escape scenario but it did not suceed! thanks for your help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `current()/local-name()` is specific to XSLT 2.0. In XSLT 1.0 you would need to write `local-name(current())`. Note that specifying xsl:version="1.0" is no guarantee that your stylesheet is conformant to XSLT 1.0.

Comment: OP's also using XPath 2.0 `fn:max()` function.